# Flutter grid system like in boostrap

Tags: flutter

does Flutter have a package to provide a grid system like in the Bootstrap framework in CSS? I know about the LayoutBuilder widget but I wanna write an application for all screen sizes and with the LayoutBuilder widget it is a lot of work...

Answer (score -1):

Try [Responsive Framework](https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_framework)

Responsive Framework has a concept of breakpoints, which is somewhat similar to grid system like in the Bootstrap framework in CSS

You can also explore [Sizer](https://pub.dev/packages/sizer)

Sizer doesn't have grid or breakpoints but enables you to specify size in percent of display height and width.